# Why doesn't this.evaluate return DOM nodes correctly?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to get an object from a web page through the `evaluate()` method so I can work with it outside the scope of `evaluate`. The element selected with name `symbol` is a `<select>` tag with 148 `<options>` (=dropdown menu).

```
casper.then(function () {
    var elmnt = this.evaluate(function () { return document.getElementsByName("symbol")[0]; });
    console.log(elmnt.options[14].index);
});

//Returns TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'elmnt.options[14].index')

casper.then(function () {
    var elmnt = this.evaluate(function () { return document.getElementsByName("symbol")[0].options[14].index; });
    console.log(elmnt);
});

//Returns 14
```

So it looks likes returning an object through the `evaluate()` method returns it incompletly since this works correctly :

```
casper.then(function () {
    var elmnt = this.evaluate(function () { return document.getElementsByName("symbol")[0]; });
    console.log(elmnt.options.length);
});

//Returns 148
```

So I can access options attributes as long as I don't read the array. Strange no ?

Comment: If you want to have access to the DOM directly in your code you may want to look at zombie.js which is a DOM/browser emulator instead of a wrapper around a real browser (webkit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense, because `elmnt.options` in the last snippet is an array full with `undefined` values. So you know the number of elements, but not their values. The reason is that DOM nodes cannot be passed from page context. The [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) say:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

So either you do everything inside of the page context (`evaluate`) or you get a representation of the DOM nodes that you want to work with. Which I think is not what you want.

```
var elmnt = this.evaluate(function () {
    return [].map.call(document.getElementsByName("symbol")[0].options, function(option){
        return {text: option.innerText, value: option.value};
    });
});
```