# jQuery returns correct number of elements, but only the first is an object

Tags: jquery, casperjs

I'm creating a `casperjs` script to parse data from a webpage. I'm using jQuery along with `casperjs`.

The problem I am having is when I try to loop through the `article` elements every element, except the first, is `null`. The script reports the correct number of elements on the page.

My code is below (I've removed part of the script as it's not required).

```
var articles = null;

/*
 * Parse all article elements
 */
casper.then(function() {

    console.log('Parsing articles from feed ...');

    articles = this.evaluate(function() {
        return $('article');
    });

    console.log(typeof(articles)); // prints 'object'

    // Prints 56
    console.log(articles.length);

});

/*
 * Parse data from article elements
 */
casper.then(function() {  
    for(i=0; i<=articles.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(articles[i]);
    }
});
```

When I run the script I get the following from the `for` loop:

```
[object Object]
null
null
null
null
null
null
...
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this.evaluate return DOM nodes correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353431/why-doesnt-this-evaluate-return-dom-nodes-correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery collection returned, in this case `$('article')`, is **not** an array. You need to iterate over it using the .each() function. *Beware, this is not the same as the $.each() function*.

See [this article](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/) for more information about how to iterate over jQuery collections.

Read up on the [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) itself:

> When creating new elements (or selecting existing ones), jQuery returns the elements in a collection. Many developers new to jQuery assume that this collection is an array. It has a zero-indexed sequence of DOM elements, some familiar array functions, and a .length property, after all. Actually, the jQuery object is more complicated than that.

Comment: I replaced the code in the `for` loop with `console.log(articles.get(i));` and `console.log(articles.eq(i));`. The loop doesn't even fire.

Comment: OP is using the `length` property and tries to access the items through indices. Both of those are supported by jQuery collections. There would be no need to use `.each()`. The reason the DOM nodes are all `null` is because they cannot be passed from the page context in PhantomJS/CasperJS (see my duplicate comment on the question).

Comment: @ArtjomB. You're right. Is this in the docs at all? I didn't see it.

Comment: It's not clearly stated in the CasperJS documentation, because it is the specific behavior of the underlying headless browser. In this case PhantomJS which clearly says in the docs that DOM node cannot be passed out of the page context.

Comment: @Artjom B. thanks for the clarification re: accessing jQuery collections.I briefly looked at the Casper js  documentation and found the [getElementsInfo()](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo). It might be of some use to you, BugHunter.

Comment: @BugHunterUK As Rhono noted the `casper.getElementsInfo()` is a common way to get a *representation* of the DOM nodes from the page to the outer context.